# Raster plot not showing symbols using plt.scatter function

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I have to do raster plot, of 1 neuron, with 10 trials of data and time is 4500 ms.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Plotting 1 neuron with 12 trials of info
maatriks = []
for i in range(1,14):
    if i<10:
        string = 'C:\\Users\\latel\\Desktop\\kool\\Neuro\\prax3\\data\\lgn\\plain\\neuron_01_stimulus_0'+str(i)+'.csv'
    else:
        string = 'C:\\Users\\latel\\Desktop\\kool\\Neuro\\prax3\\data\\lgn\\plain\\neuron_01_stimulus_'+str(i)+'.csv'
data_in = np.genfromtxt(string,dtype = 'int', delimiter = ',' or '\n')
maatriks.append(data_in)

data = np.array(maatriks)
print data.shape

spikes = np.array(data[8])
print spikes.shape

nonzeros = 0

for i,item in enumerate(spikes):
    nonzeros += np.count_nonzero(item)
    plt.scatter(item, i*np.ones(item.shape), marker = '|')
print nonzeros

plt.ylim(-1,len(spikes))
plt.xlim(0,len(spikes[0]))
plt.xlabel("Time is seconds")
plt.ylabel("Trial number")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This outputs me(the prints) :

(13L, 10L, 4501L)

(10L, 4501L)

55

But the plot is empty , i cannot understand why the plot is empty. There should be 55 lines in my opinion ...

Edit: Got it working. Added this code.

```
for row in spikes:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if (row[i] == 1):
            row[i] = i
```

Because the data was only 0 or 1.

Anyone know how to do it shorter ?